# facebook like button not showing?

Tags: html

ive been going at this for hours now,  everybody tells me "it works here jsbinurl"
but when i copy the exact code in my notepad++ file it doesnt i even created a brand new with this exact same code as the jsbin and it doesnt show, i tried in 3 different computers and still nothing

see here in my jsbin it works fine:

http://jsbin.com/uhejis/1/edit

but i tried it on my local html page on three computers, xp, vista, and 7 and nothing whats wrong with it?? does this code work on your computer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on my localhost in safari, chrome, ie9, opera and firefox. 
There might be a problem with your connection or firewall.